# What value should peer.gossip.bootstrap property of a peer be set to?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger Fabric official documentation( https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gossip.html#external-and-internal-endpoints ) mentioned that "The peer.gossip.bootstrap property in the core.yaml of the peer is used to bootstrap gossip within an organization. If you are using gossip, you will typically configure all the peers in your organization to point to an initial set of bootstrap peers (you can specify a space-separated list of peers).". I don't quite understand that. My questions are:

1. If an organization org1 has four peers, A,B,C and D, can A and B be
   set as bootstrap peers, and then both C and D are bootstrapped by A
   and B?
2. If yes, should the peer.gossip.bootstrap property in C and D's
   core.yaml be set to a list of A and B's core addresses, such as
   "A:7051,B:7051"?
3. Both A and B are bootstrap peers, what value should their
   peer.gossip.bootstrap property be set to?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If an organization org1 has four peers, A,B,C and D, can A and B be set as bootstrap peers, and then both C and D are bootstrapped by A and B?

Yes, you can setup A and B to be a bootstrap set. Then C and D will learn membership connecting thru these peers.

> 2. If yes, should the peer.gossip.bootstrap property in C and D's core.yaml be set to a list of A and B's core addresses, such as "A:7051,B:7051"?

This is precisely how it works.

> 3. Both A and B are bootstrap peers, what value should their peer.gossip.bootstrap property be set to?

Same as for C and D.

Comment: Thanks. So this means that A and B must be launched before launching C and D, right?

Comment: Yes, sure. They need to be up and running so C and D should be able to connect to.

Comment: Got it. So peer.gossip.bootstrap property is only useful when a peer is launched, and after the peer is launched successfully and running smoothly, peer.gossip.bootstrap property is of no use, right?

Comment: Yes, this is why it called bootstrap ;)

Comment: OK, thanks, the last question: can every peer set itself as the bootstrap peer?

Comment: What does it mean every peer sets itself? This configuration should be the same for peers in org.

Comment: I mean, let's say there are three peers in org1. Can we set peer0.org1's bootstrap as peer0.org1, peer1.org1's bootstrap as peer1.org1, and peer2.org1's bootstrap as peer2.org1?

Comment: You need to bootstrap peer with other peer in your setup, and you'd better keep this consistent and make all peers to bootstrap with the same one. And in your example if even won't work, since it's meaningless to start each peer with itself. Cause you need some rendezvous point to make every to "meet" (connect) to it, hence you will be sure everyone doing the same eventually will meet everyone.